# Testing USSD applications

Tags: testing, ussd

The application that is being developed currently in my project involves USSD shortcodes and interacting with the server thru shortcodes.

This app is targeted towards low end java phones, so usage of smartphones is currently out of scope.

Is there any way of automating USSD applications? This necessarily need not be on the phones, it can be on the computer too.

Thanks-
Siva

Answer (score 2):

Siva, since you are dealing with java, your can try smslib (http://smslib.org/ - java code for sending sms/ussd via GSM modem attched to you desktop machine). You can set up the Jenkins, running the maven build, which call the TestNG tests, that call the smslib code, which request some ussd and analyze the request and asserts the build.

Comment: I've created a post asking how smslib can be used for ussd: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268389/smslib-example-for-interactive-ussd-session)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of USSD, you ccan place the application on a web server where the Telcom or gateway you use for USSD will pass you the requests sent from the phones and you send a response back based on request that is then forwarded back to the client making the USSD request.