# SMSLib example for interactive USSD session

Tags: ussd, smslib

I have a USSD application that provides an interactive session for users, for example:

```
User> Dial USSD Shortcode
Serv> Return Main Menu
User> Select Option 1, e.g. "View Movie Times"
Serv> Return List of Cities
User> Select Option 3, e.g. Mumbai
Serv> Return List of Cinemas
User> etc ...
```

I would like to test the USSD Server by using SMSLib to simulate the user.

Are there any example SMSLib code snippets that show how to perform an interactive USSD session with a USSD server?

Comment: There is one other problem.  I forgot that after dialing the USSD Shortcode, the USSD Server does a USSD push back to the user and the rest of the user's session continues from that.

Comment: how to do ussd sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/smslib/issues/attachmentText?id=318&aid=-1267774050858280969&name=SendUSSD.java) gives an example of sending and receiving USSD data using smslib:

> ```
> // SendUSSD.java - Sample application.
> //
> // This application shows you the basic procedure for sending messages.
> // You will find how to send synchronous and asynchronous messages.
> //
> // For asynchronous dispatch, the example application sets a callback
> // notification, to see what's happened with messages.
>
> package examples.modem;
>
> import org.smslib.AGateway;
> import org.smslib.AGateway.Protocols;
> import org.smslib.IUSSDNotification;
> import org.smslib.Library;
> import org.smslib.Service;
> import org.smslib.USSDResponse;
> import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;
>
> public class SendUSSD
> {
>         public void doIt() throws Exception
>         {
>                 Service srv;
>       USSDNotification ussdNotification = new USSDNotification();
>                 System.out.println("Example: Send USSD Command from a serial gsm modem.");
>                 System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
>                 System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
>                 srv = new Service();
>                 SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM4", 19200, "Huawei", "E220");
>                 gateway.setProtocol(Protocols.PDU);
>       gateway.setInbound(true);
>                 gateway.setOutbound(true);
>                 gateway.setSimPin("0000");
>       srv.setUSSDNotification(ussdNotification);
>                 srv.addGateway(gateway);
>                 srv.startService();
>                 System.out.println();
>                 System.out.println("Modem Information:");
>                 System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
>                 System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
>                 System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
>                 System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
>                 System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + "%");
>                 System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
>                 System.out.println();
>
>       String resp = gateway.sendUSSDCommand("*888#"); // not working
> //      String resp = gateway.sendCustomATCommand("AT+CUSD=1,\"*888#\",15\r"); // working
>       System.out.println(resp);
>
>       System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
>                 System.in.read();
>                 srv.stopService();
>         }
>
>    public class USSDNotification implements IUSSDNotification
>    {
>       public void process(AGateway gateway, USSDResponse response) {
>                         System.out.println("USSD handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
>                         System.out.println(response);
>       }
>    }
>
>         public static void main(String args[])
>         {
>                 SendUSSD app = new SendUSSD();
>                 try
>                 {
>                         app.doIt();
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception e)
>                 {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>         }
> }
> ```

Comment: it looks like this code no longer works in the newest modem api. At least, I see only send message and send at command methods there.